# Creating a Class with specific methods in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, parameter-passing

I have 10 specific methods on my code, and I want to use them with a Class Object like this one:

```
void function(){
//do Something that I want
}

class PoseAction{

Pose pose;

void methodDesirable();

PoseAction(Pose ps, Method function()){

  this.pose = ps;
  this.methodDesirable() = function();
}

}
```

So when I create a new Object

```
PoseAction ps = new PoseAction(pose1, action1());
```

calling 
     ps.methodDesirable();

it will call action1() function.

It's possible to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: None of this is valid Java. You can't pass methods or functions in Java. But it seems like what you're looking for is the strategy pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: This is only possible with a liberal application of bytecode manipulation and reflection. Also, you'd be going against the grain in the context of Java, the language.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are not first class objects in java. That is, you can not directly assign them or pass them as method parameters. You need to use objects and interfaces:

```
interface Action {
    void fire(Pose pose);
}

class PoseAction {
    Action action;
    Pose pose;

    void methodDesirable() {
        action.fire(pose)
    }

    PoseAction(Pose ps, Action a) {
        pose = ps;
        action = a;
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
PoseAction ps = new PoseAction(pose1, new Action() {
     public void fire(Pose pose) {
          action1(pose);
     }
};
ps.methodDesirable();
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible in such way, Java doesn't support [delegates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegate_%28CLI%29). In java that can be done with interfaces:

```
interface Command {
    void doCommand();
}

PoseAction pa = new PoseAction(new Pose(), new Command() {
    @Override
    public void doCommand() {
        //method body
    }
});
```

Here `new Command() {...}` is anonymous inner class that implements `Command` Interface